# Parse a graph url to get search, filter, select parameters

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I have the following code in C# to make a graph call:

```
public async Task<IGraphServiceUsersCollectionPage> GetResponseAsync(string s)
{            

    var queryOptions = new List<QueryOption>()
    {
        new QueryOption("$count", "true"),
        new QueryOption("$search", "")
    };

    return await graphServiceClient
                        .Users
                        .Request(queryOptions)
                        .Header("ConsistencyLevel", "eventual")
                        .Filter("")
                        .Select("")
                        .OrderBy("")                        
                        .GetAsync();
    });
}
```

an example of string s is "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$count=true&$search="displayName:room"&$filter=endsWith(mail,'microsoft.com')&$orderBy=displayName&$select=id,displayName,mail"

how do I parse this string so that I can pass:

> displayName:room as Search value

> endsWith(mail,'microsoft.com') as Filter value

> displayName and OrderBy value

> id,displayName,mail as Select value

to the code?

```
public async Task<IGraphServiceUsersCollectionPage> GetResponseAsync(string s)
{            

            var queryOptions = new List<QueryOption>()
            {
                new QueryOption("$count", "true"),
                new QueryOption("$search", "\"displayName:room\"")
            };

            return await _graphServiceClient
                                .Users
                                .Request(queryOptions)
                                .Header("ConsistencyLevel", "eventual")
                                .Filter("endsWith(mail,'microsoft.com')")
                                .Select("id,displayName,mail")
                                .OrderBy("displayName")                                
                                .GetAsync();
}
```

UPDATE:

Same for places, here is what I have tried based on the answer below:

```
            var queryParamValues = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(url, Encoding.UTF8);            
            var filterValue = queryParamValues["$filter"];      
            var selectValue = queryParamValues["$select"];

            var queryOptions = new List<QueryOption>() { new QueryOption("$count", "true") };         
            var roomUrl = _graphServiceClient.Places.AppendSegmentToRequestUrl("microsoft.graph.room");
            var request = new GraphServicePlacesCollectionRequest(roomUrl, _graphServiceClient, queryOptions);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filterValue)) { request = (GraphServicePlacesCollectionRequest)request.Filter(filterValue); }            
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectValue)) { request = (GraphServicePlacesCollectionRequest)request.Select(selectValue); }

            return await request
                            .Top(MaxResultCount)
                            .GetAsync();
```

Comment: Didn't the above code work for you? That is the exact same code in the Graph Explorer's code snippet. What error are you seeing after running the above code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [HttpUtility.ParseQueryString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.parsequerystring?view=net-6.0) method and read value of each query parameter.

```
var url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$count=true&$search=\"displayName:room\"&$filter=endsWith(mail,'microsoft.com')&$orderBy=displayName&$select=id,displayName,mail";

var queryParamValues = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(url, Encoding.UTF8);
var searchValue = queryParamValues["$search"];
var filterValue = queryParamValues["$filter"];
var orderValue = queryParamValues["$orderBy"];
var selectValue = queryParamValues["$select"];

var queryOptions = new List<QueryOption>()
    {
        new QueryOption("$count", "true")
    };

// if search parameter not missing in url
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchValue))
{
    queryOptions.Add(new QueryOption("$search", searchValue));
}

// create base request
var request =  _graphServiceClient
                        .Users
                        .Request(queryOptions)
                        .Header("ConsistencyLevel", "eventual");

// if filter parameter not missing in url
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filterValue))
{
    request = request.Filter(filterValue);
}

// if orderby parameter not missing in url
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(orderValue))
{
    request = request.OrderBy(orderValue);
}

// if select parameter not missing in url
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectValue))
{
    request = request.Select(selectValue);
}
        
return await request 
             .Top(MaxResultCount)
             .GetAsync();
```

Comment: I tried the same I see queryParamValues but I see error:  Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. (Parameter 'index')

Comment: @user989988 Could you share more details about the exception? Which line throws the exception? var searchValue = queryParamValues["$search"];?

Comment: Failed to deserialize exception from TaskActivity: {"$type":"Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException, Microsoft.Graph.Core","Error":{"$type":"Microsoft.Graph.Error, Microsoft.Graph.Core","code":"BadRequest","message":"Expression expected at position 0 in ''.","innererror":{"$type":"Microsoft.Graph.Error, Microsoft.Graph.Core"

Comment: if one of the parameters is missing from the url - example: "graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/…" $search is missing. How do I handle that?

Comment: @user989988 See updated answer. You need to build the request. Check if value searchValue, filterValue, orderValue and selectValue is not null.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could you please check my UPDATE section and let me know if that looks correct for Places?